# How to setup a Scala hello world app with Akka and Sl4j logging?

Tags: scala, logging, akka, slf4j

I'm not new to programming, but the amount of disparate content around there around logging is making my head spin.

**Mission:** To get a basic Scala app daemon with an actor that listens to a RabbitMQ message.

Now I do not need help with the RabbitMQ or Akka part, I just need to setup logging to a file and console with a modern (stable, standard) logging library such as slf4j (in other words no random guy's github account). Something that will be maintained long term.

Here's what I go so far:

## /build.sbt

```
 name := "BOGen"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq {
  "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor" % "2.0"
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2"
  "com.typesafe" %% "scalalogging-slf4j" % "1.0.1"
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.1"
  "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.1"
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.3"
}
```

## src/main/scala/main.scala

```
package com.mycom.mydepartment.someapp


import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging

object Main extends LazyLogging {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    logger.info("Hello From My app!") // this should log to console and file
  }

}
```

## src/main/resources/logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <File>./logs/myapp.log</File>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

## src/main/resoruces/application.conf

```
akka {
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "INFO"
}
```

The current error I get with this setup:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\dana.murad\.sbt\0.13\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\PROJECTS\active\BOGen\project
[info] Set current project to BOGen (in build file:/C:/PROJECTS/active/BOGen/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\PROJECTS\active\BOGen\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\PROJECTS\active\BOGen\src\main\scala\com\echostar\sse\voldemort\main.scala:4: object typesafe is not a member of package com
[error] import com.typesafe.scalalogging.slf4j.LazyLogging
[error]            ^
[error] C:\PROJECTS\...\src\main\scala\...\main.scala:6: not found: type LazyLogging
[error] object Main extends LazyLogging {
[error]                     ^
[error] C:\PROJECTS\...\src\main\scala\...\voldemort\main.scala:9: not found: value logger
[error]     logger.info("Hello From My app!")
[error]     ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 23, 2016 10:50:21 PM
```

Now I get that it's not finding LazyLogging, but everywhere I read my code seems to be identical (build.sbt dependencies, import line and usage). I've tried many different scenarios and different logging methods, this is just my current setup.

Can someone point me to a quick straight-forward tutorial or book to set this up. For the love of scala I just need this basic app to log to a file and console when I hit sbt run.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the cause, but you have at least two visible problems:

1. Your `build.sbt` is missing commas in the dependency list
2. Your main class is called `Main` but is sitting inside a file called `main`

#### Edit

You also use an old version of [scala-logging](https://github.com/typesafehub/scala-logging). I would suggest running `sbt compile` and following its errors. From that stage the corrections would be quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your libraryDependencies was having typo (missing comma). Also, you were using incorrect (older) versions of the dependencies. Replace your build.sbt with this:

```
name := "BOGen"

   version := "1.0"

   scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

   resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.10",
    "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.4.10",
    "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",
    "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.1",
    "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.7.1",
    "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.3"
   )
```